# ngrok dynamic address in DDNS instead of router IP address?

Tags: ddns, ngrok

disclaimer: I have no experience at networking so my question might sound stupid.

I'm trying to get access to HomeAssistant running on a local Raspberry Pi. I tried to setup DuckDNS and port forwarding but with no success. My router tells me that it is behind double NAT so it is not possible to access it from the outside (probably my ISP uses CGNAT).

The second option is to use ngrok. It works well until the first reboot. My thoughts are that ngrok dynamic address is like a dynamic IP address now. So if I update DDNS with IP address of that dynamic ngrok address instead of IP address of my router it should work. But I'm not sure if it is possible and how can I do this.

So is it possible to register the ngrok dynamic address in DuckDNS? How can I do this? Should I find a repo with a DuckDNS script and modify it?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to solve this.

- [One is to pay for ngrok](https://ngrok.com/pricing) - the pro plan will reserve a static IP address for you.
- The other is to use your own script. Per the [DuckDNS docs](https://www.duckdns.org/spec.jsp), all you need to do is make a web request matching the format:

`https://www.duckdns.org/update?domains={YOURVALUE}&token={YOURVALUE}[&ip={YOURVALUE}][&ipv6={YOURVALUE}][&verbose=true][&clear=true]`

..and you can set the DNS to anything you want.